# How can I make the sidebar appear by default in a custom Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-my-maps

I would like to have the sidebar shown by default in the new version of the custom Google Maps. Is there any way to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot find the link now, but am certain that I've read (on a Google help site or similar) this is controlled by the screen-width of the device of the person who is looking at the map - effectively meaning that you cannot control it.

Comment: Please let me know once you have found the reference. Thanks!